# How to animate infinite rotary movement

Tags: animation, blender, unreal-4

I would like to add a chainsaw (or something similar to it... a rotary blade) to my game as a melee weapon. In fact, a rotary blade is a better example.

Would it be better to do it in blender somehow, using skeleton, or should I just create two parts (the handle and the blade) and then rotate it in UE4?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there is no "better" in cases like this. Whatever works for you works. However, to convey the image of a running chainsaw, you might want to add a little shake to the engine. 
You could do all that by scaling the model slightly up and down based on time passed in unreal engine, but you'd have much more direct control over it if you rigged and animated the model. That way, you can see what happens the moment you edit it.

Comment: You mentioned "unity". I presume you mean "Unreal" since the question is tagged as such?

Comment: True, I mentioned Unreal - but in this case, I don't think the difference would be huge :)

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right. I'll edit it. But exactly, it makes no difference to my recommendation. Because that's what it is. There is not one right way to do it, but this is how I would do it.